# JSP: How to add the values of "each word" and display the sum as "sentence"?

Tags: javascript, jsp

[JSP] I am creating a text analysis website and have problems with adding up the values of a sentence.

Basically, each word has a polarity (either a positive or negative number).

In Part (1), I split the passage input into sentences.

In part (2), I get the "polarity" value of **EACH WORD** from the input and wanted to add up the total for **EACH SENTENCE** and display accordingly.

However, the code below does not work. May I know what is the problem? Please help...thanks...

---

**Part (1)**

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {

   if (words[j].getPOS().equals("wf")||words[j].getWord().equals(",")||words[j].getWord().equals("，")||words[j].getPOS().equals("ww")||words[j].getPOS().equals("wt")||words[j].getPOS().equals("wj")) {
           sb.append(words[j].getWord());
       sb.append( "<br> ");
   }
   else{sb.append(words[j].getWord());}} 
 String parsedResult = sb.toString();
 String[] sen=parsedResult.split("<br> ");*
```

**Part (2)**

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();
double[] polarity = words[i].getPolarity();
String posScore = String.format("%.4f", polarity[0]);
String negScore = String.format("%.4f", polarity[1]);
sb2.append("<TR>");
sb2.append("<TD>"+sen[i]+"</TD>");
sb2.append("<TD>"+negScore+"</TD>");
sb2.append("<TD>"+posScore+"</TD>");
sb2.append("</TR>");*
```

Comment: "However, the code below does not work" You need to explain what the code you have tried does, e.g. are you seeing an exception? Is the output slightly wrong? Does it crash your computer and make your light bulbs blink?

Comment: thx for the comment. in the table, in the column for Positive score and Negative score, all rows show "0". If I change "sb2.append("<TD>"+sen[i]+"</TD>");" to "sb2.append("<TD>"+words[i]+"</TD>");", it works perfectly fine and shows values of each row (i.e. for each word). I guess the problem arises because the polarity value I get is for each WORD, and some more codes are needed to add them up and become the polarity values of a SENTENCE.

Comment: If you add the extra information to your question you may get more help

Comment: [link](http://dsme4200.baf.cuhk.edu.hk/14gp04/Polarity/) Here is the link of the output. The system is built to analyse some Chinese passages. Here is a sample input of Chinese if you want to see the output. "從鏡頭選擇的角度而言，營造淺景深效果的優先選擇，必數大光圈鏡頭及遠攝鏡頭。如果有一支鏡頭，能同時具備大光圈及遠攝規格，絕對能稱得上是一支夢幻人像鏡頭！近月上市的 Olympus M.ZUIKO DIGITAL ED 40-150mm f/2.8 PRO 專業級遠攝變焦鏡頭，便正正是箇中例子。此鏡的最近對焦距離只是 0.7 米，因此即使是拍攝臉部特寫，也一樣無問題。"